# Java: not check for impossible state in method call

Tags: java, error-handling

I know that by the semantics of removeContract, and removeIssuer, and the design of the code (getPrice is package local so I am the one calling it), the method getPrice cannot be called with a contract or issuer of the contract that was previously removed. In a sense getPrice has the pre-condition that the contract is in the HashMap "contracts".

However, is it bad practice relying on such assumptions and not check for it? Should I add `checkArgument(contracts.contains(contract))` and `checkArgument(issuers.contains(issuer))`?

PS: Contract and Issuer are both immutable classes.

```
public class Market {
  private HashMap<Integer, Contract> contracts;
  private HashMap<Integer, Issuer> issuers;

  // ...

  public Contract removeContract(Contract contract) { // ... } 
  public Issuer removeIssuer(Issuer issuer) { // ... } 

  double getPrice(Contract contract) {
    checkArgument(contract != null, "Contract cannot be null");

    Issuer issuer = issuers.get(contract.getIssuerId());

    return issuer.getPriceDistribution().sample();
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: That probably depends on where and how you are using it (I'd definitely mention it in the JavaDoc though). If you are able to fix code that violates the contract and be able to track NPEs that occur in `getPrice()` to that code it might be fine not to check. If a 3rd party is calling your code or you're having difficulties to track the reason for a NPE (especially if that happens often) it would probably be best to add those checks in order to provide a more meaningful message or even exception to the caller and make sure the NPEs you get aren't caused by violated contracts.

Comment: if you are sure there can't be errors, don't double check never, but **YOU MUST BE REALLY SURE** of what is going on